# Play Store: revert app bundle to use apk

Tags: android, google-play

I'm going to submit an update to my app using [App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/build) announced recently by Google. My question is: will it be possible to roll back to submitting APKs once I published App Bundle? Is it possible to submit an update of the app back with APK, after the submission with App Bundle was made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any new release (ie version code increment) you can choose to use an App Bundle or an APK. So you can use an App Bundle for version 2, then switch back to APK for version 3 if you prefer.

Comment: That sounds good. Do you have any link to official documentation?

Comment: It's not explicitly said, but at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011 you can see that you can activate or deactivate any APK or bundle

Comment: For the APK in version 3, is it still possible for this to be a self-signed, or is this signed by Google App Signing process post upload?

Answer (score 1):

Reactivating old releases is no longer possible. You may be able to make a new release and select a previously released .apk then change its version # in the console. This does not seem to be possible with app bundles. I just tried and it gave me a bunch of warnings as well as disabled the release button